# Rails Realtime Chat: Is it secure to implement it with just plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, chat, ujs

I've added a realtime chat to my rails application using only vanilla javascript. I've included it below. I'm just wondering, are there any security issues just looking at the code I've provided? I'm just not sure whether there's any issues with AJAX injections or any unknown unknowns I need to worry about. I didn't add ActionCable mainly because I don't need all of its functionality. Thanks for your help! :)

A chat has many private messages between 2 users. Users have many messages. I've added policies using pundit so only authorized users can access chats. And I'm using devise so only logged in users can access chats. Every model uses UUID.

chats/show.html.erb

```
<% if @messages %>
  <div id="messages">
    <%= render @messages %>
  </div>
<% end %>      
<%= form_with(model: [@chat, Message.new], local: false, html: { id: "message-form" }) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.text_area :content, placeholder: "Send a message" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

messages/_message.html.erb

```
<%= message.user.name %>
<%= message.content %>
```

messages/create.js.erb

```
var messages = document.querySelector("#messages");
messages.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<%= j render(@message) %>"); 
document.getElementById("message-form").reset();
```

controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
def create
  @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
  @message = @chat.messages.build(message_params)
  @message.user = current_user
  authorize @message
  
  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.save
      format.html { redirect_to @chat, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
      format.js
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @chat }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @chat, alert: 'Message not created.' }
      format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

controllers/chats_controller.rb

```
 def show                                      
   @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
   @chats = @listing.chats
   @chat = Chat.find(params[:id])
   if @chat.messages
     @messages = @chat.messages
   end
 end
```

Comment: Looks like I could post a message to any given `chat_id` just by manipulating the params. I'd say that's a security flaw. Depending on how you've written your show action I imagine I could go read them too.

Comment: Hey @Jon, thanks for the reply! I'm currently using UUID for all of my models, so I would think that should prevent issues with anyone trying to change the params. I'm a bit more worried about the javascript.